# DebugHandler Depricated in latest Jetty Version, how to properly shutdown?

Tags: java, jetty

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18342014/shutting-down-jetty-using-shutdownhandler) of how to enable an `shutdownhandler` for Embedded Jetty

when I try to use it with a `newer Jetty Version` I get deprecated warnings.

What would be the proper way to *Implement a shutdown handler* for the latest Jetty version ?

**[Edit]**

tried to add shutdown functionality with.
ShutdownHandler shutdownHandler = new ShutdownHandler("switchoff", true, 
true);

but got 404 with
http://localhost:22279/shutdown?token="switchoff"

Welcome Page does work with
http://localhost:22279/

Comment: Your edit indicates a different question.   First question was about deprecation warning, the next one about http 404 responses.

Comment: will create a new question for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DebugHandler` is not necessary for shutdown.

If you are using embedded jetty, you can just keep a reference to the `Server` object and call `Server.stop()` when you want it to shut down.

otherwise ...

The `ShutdownHandler` can still be used, it has not been disabled or deprecated.

[org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/ShutdownHandler.java](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.3.8.v20160314/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/ShutdownHandler.java)

The javadoc even has a snippet that shows its use.

[API Docs: org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ShutdownHandler](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/ShutdownHandler.html)

Comment: thanks again for your reply...actually it was an eclipse hint for the debug handler

Comment: Edited the question. Not sure if a new Problem. Any additionaly hint ?